# Make the path level smaller for msbuild zip file that is deployed as a web package

Tags: azure, msbuild, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

I'm using MSBUILD to build a solution that only contains a ASP.NET Web Application project. This is the exact line that I used to do this,

`msbuild webapp.sln /p:Configuration="Release" /p:DeployOnBuild=true`

Now this builds a zip file containing the web package files but it is all contained within a really long folder structure. Now for a bit of context. I've got an app service in Azure that I was publishing my project to using the "Publish" feature in Visual Studio 2019. This published the files under the "wwwroot/Files" folder in Azure. Now the problem I have now is that when this zip file is deployed to my app service in Azure, my "wwwroot/Files" folder now contains the following folder structure,

\Content\C_C\Source Control Root\Version\Type\Workspace\Solution\Project\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\

Basically what was being published from within Visual Studio 2019 to the "wwwroot/Files" is now being published to "wwwroot/Files/Content/C_C/Source Control Root/Version/Type/Workspace/Solution/Project/obj/Release/Package/PackageTmp/".

I want to be able to mimic what was done before with the "Publish" feature in VS 2019 by creating a zip file of the web package files without it being nested in a really long folder structure. Is it possible to achieve this? If so how would this be done?

P.S I use the following Powershell script to deploy the zip file to Azure,

```
Publish-AzWebapp -ResourceGroupName $resgroup -Name $name -ArchivePath "C:/SomewhereLocal~\WebhookBot.zip"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need [Deploy your app to Azure App Service with a ZIP or WAR file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip).

Firstly, choose **publish as folder** in VS.
[image]
Click Publish, which will generate a folder with publish file like below. I compressed the content and named it `MyWebApp.zip` , which we will use it deploy to Azure app service later.
[image]
Follow the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip#with-powershell) about deploy from ZIP file.
[image]
Check the file content in wwwroot:
[image]